Filter and delete rows with multiple versions of prefixed text
I pull a report from Power BI into Excel. Current coding deletes bottom three rows, removes rows with duplicate PO numbers in Column A (1), filters and removes every entry except "Approved" in Column J (10).
There are thousands of lines left which need filtering and deleting.
Column H (8) is where names are input in the original program. When an action has been taken we prefix this with an "R". Each colleague has their own way of doing this. There are other prefixes.
We want to remove all prefixed entries from the worksheet.
The most common theme is an "R" followed by a space or a hyphen. Below is a capture of the ones I've spotted so far, with Test Text input rather than names. Real Data is to reflect where a name we want to retain might start with an R, i.e. Rebecca and the XX or * prefix is another one we filter and delete.
R - Test Text
R Test Text
R-Test Text
RTest Text
Real Data
R-
R Test Text
R- Test Text
R_Test Text
XX Test Text
*Test Text

The ones with RTest Text probably will have to be done manually but can rows with all other instances be removed via VBA?
I tried coding but it deleted everything I wanted and left a few entries that I didn't want.
Option Explicit
Sub RsRemovalTest()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, LRow As Long
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    LRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , 1, 2).Row
    
    ws.Cells(LRow, 1).Offset(-2).Resize(3).EntireRow.Delete
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
        .AutoFilter 10, "<>Approved"
        If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address <> .Rows(1).Address Then
            .Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        .AutoFilter 8, "R *", 2, "R-*", 3, "XX*"
        If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address <> .Rows(1).Address Then
            .Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    
End Sub


Is "H:H" the last column of the range to be processed?

Columns range from A - Z but the 3 which need processing for duplicates, filters etc are A, H and J. Number of rows can vary. This was where I initially approached a forum as my Record Macro steps only worked on the range I selected on the original data test and not the extended data range I made up for additional testing, rather than using an LRow as Long argument. Also the guy who helped wrote a much better code than my somewhat garbled Record Macro option did. Must go and re-thank him profusely as well as yourself!


I did not ask about number of rows... So, H:H is not the last column of the range to be processed. Anyhow, I calculated which to be the next empty column after the last one. 2. I do not care about any other forum. I can help you only if I understand what you really need, not what has been done somewhere else. 3. I am afraid I cannot understand your question. I tried answering only filtering by strings in H:H which should have the structure you have shown in your question. Other filtering/processing which you did not talked about should be done as you want.


You need advanced filter to use multiple criteria.
Look here: How to filter for multiple criteria in Excel?
If you want the filter to trigger automatically every time you change the criteria, use this macro (put it in worksheet object module):
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:I5")) Is Nothing Then 'change range with filter criteria
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        Range("A7").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'A7 is the first cell of filtered range, A1 is the first cell of range with criteria
    End If
End Sub


Please, also try the next way, using a helper column. It uses arrays for faster processing:
Sub FilterMultipleCriteria()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastEmptyCol As Long, hlpCell As Range
  Dim arr, arrH, i As Long, boolFound As Boolean
  Const helpCol As String = "Helper" 'the helper column header
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use the necessary one
  If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
  
  lastR = ws.Range("H" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on H:H
  lastEmptyCol = ws.cells(1, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column + 1 'last empty column
  
  arr = ws.Range("H2:H" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
  ReDim arrH(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)  'redim the helper array
  
  'process arr and issue the helper array:
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    Select Case left(arr(i, 1), 2)
        Case "R ", "R-", "R_"
            arrH(i, 1) = "Del": boolFound = True
    End Select
    If Not boolFound Then
        If left(arr(i, 1), 5) = "RTest" Then
            arrH(i, 1) = "Del": boolFound = True
        End If
    End If
    If Not boolFound Then
        If arr(i, 1) = "Real Data" Then
            arrH(i, 1) = "Del": boolFound = True
        End If
    End If
    If Not boolFound Then
        If left(arr(i, 1), 5) = "*Test" Then
            arrH(i, 1) = "Del": boolFound = True
        End If
    End If
    boolFound = False
  Next i
  
  'set the helper column header
  Set hlpCell = ws.cells(1, lastEmptyCol)
    
    With hlpCell
        .value = helpCol 'place the header
        .offset(1).Resize(UBound(arrH), 1).Value2 = arrH 'drop the array content
    End With
  
  'filter by helper column:
  hlpCell.AutoFilter hlpCell.column, "Del"
  
  Dim rngVis As Range 'visible cells range
  On Error Resume Next
   Set rngVis = ws.Range("H2:H" & lastR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Not rngVis Is Nothing Then
    rngVis.EntireRow.Delete    'delete the marked rows
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False  'remove the filter
    hlpCell.EntireColumn.Clear 'clear the helper column
  End If
End Sub


Hi Fane, I managed to copy and apply your first suggestion with success - thank you so much, you have no idea how many hours over a week (this report is done daily and is easily over 3000 lines long) you will have spared myself or anyone else doing it.

The second code you used to replace the first had some issues. Instead of returning the "Real Data" entries expected in column H, there were only blanks (intentionally left to account for ones left blank in the original system, or XX entries. Also, it didn't return just the approved entries in column J but a mix of all the following: Approved, Rejected, Awaiting Service Approval, Cancelled, Created, Awaiting Value Approval.

At risk of incurring wrath, there are two other reports that tend to be run off the same data export. The coding written to filter column 10 (.AutoFilter 10, "<>Approved"), I amended that to one of the other status', however, when trying to put a comma and second criteria to see if that would work, it didn't return what I wanted. Was looking at a total of 3 reports in all: 1 - Approved,2 - Awaiting Service Approval and Awaiting Value Approval and 3 - Created, Cancelled and Rejected. I obviously missed something fundamental by adding additional status' in the code but again, didn't have a clue.

@SalsaMoon I cannot understand what "second code" does mean. It is only a code I posted... I cannot understand your second comment. Don't you have the strings to be evaluated in column "H:H" as you say in your question? If not, what did you mean by Column H (8) is where names are input in the original program? What about column "J" you are talking about? To maintain the rows where there is "Approved" in "J:J"? I am afraid I could not understand your question and the community rules state to not answer such a question... Did you say anything about three reports and what this means?

@SalsaMoon I also suggested to edit your question and place a picture showing part of such a text file and another one showing how the dummy content of the text file must be split on sheets. At least, show the text file and clearly explain for each line WHERE to be copied and BASED ON WHAT.
